# Change camera position distance in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js, camera, orbital-mechanics

In ThreeJS, I am trying to bring my camera closer to the rendered mesh so it's taking up more of the viewport. I have messed around with the camera.position.set values but these only seem to change the rotation, not actually bring it closer/further away from the object.

I'm using the OrbitControls module and think this may be overriding the default settings, but am a bit stumped as to how the distance can be changed?

Any help is much appreciated.

[Full source](http://dev.3dprintertoolbox.com/threejs/slicer.html)

```
    function init() {

        // renderer
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: artifactCanvas, antialias: true } );
        renderer.setSize(800, 600);

        // scene
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.add( new THREE.GridHelper( build_plate_size_mm, build_plate_grid_segments ) );
        scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xc5e5fc );

        // camera
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 3000 );
        camera.position.set( 1000, 500, 1000 );
        camera.lookAt( 0, 200, 0 );

        //controls
        orbit = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        orbit.update();
        orbit.addEventListener( 'change', render );

        control = new THREE.TransformControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        control.showY = false;
        control.addEventListener( 'change', render );
        control.addEventListener( 'dragging-changed', function ( event ) {
            orbit.enabled = ! event.value;
        } );
```

[image]

Comment: Why not put your minimal repoducible example in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: Don't you miss `scene.add(camera)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the position of the camera via the THREE.Vector3 method.

> camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

[Refrence](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt)